# Polymer element not working

Tags: polymer

Just trying to run the demo code [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/creatingelements.html) but I get some error in my console saying:

```
Warning: platform.js is not the first script on the page. 

See http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/platform.html#setup for details. platform.js:12
'window.webkitStorageInfo' is deprecated. Please use 'navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage' or 'navigator.webkitPersistentStorage' instead. platform.js:12
XHR finished loading: "http://localhost:8000/elements/color-picker.html". platform.js:14
Uncaught Error: UNSPECIFIED_EVENT_TYPE_ERR: DOM Events Exception 0 catcher.js:208
XHR finished loading: "http://localhost:8000/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html". platform.js:14
Uncaught Error: UNSPECIFIED_EVENT_TYPE_ERR: DOM Events Exception 0 catcher.js:208
XHR finished loading: "http://localhost:8000/bower_components/polymer/layout.html".
```

PS: I am testing it on chrome Version 28.0.1500.95.

Thanks!

Comment: chrome version 28 is quite old, the latest stable is 37. Can you tell me which example you were trying to run?

Comment: The color picker one, but I also tried with others and I am getting the same issue.

Comment: Installed the beta 38, it worked. Can we give this info in error log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @robdodson, updating the chrome to latest version resolves the issue.